# Looping without a loop

Tags: c++

We have been restricted us to not use a loop in a program as a programming challenge.

> Restrictions:
>   You can not use while, for, goto and recursion.

The restrictions are pretty daunting. I couldn't really think of any proper solution.
So I opted for this one which is achieved by modifying the return address.

Could this be any better?

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void the__(){}
void magic__(){}
void loop__(){}
void function__(){}
void here__(){}

template <typename T>
struct for_
{
    bool started = false;
    void* fix = nullptr;
    void(*body)(T&) = nullptr;

    for_(void(*body)(T&))
        : body(body)
    {
        auto do_for__ = uintptr_t(do_for_);
        uint64_t magic[] = {5243466812662057800, 6135086863767628931ull, 10416984888688609608ull, 144};
        mprotect((void*)(do_for__-do_for__%4096), 4096, 7);
        std::memcpy((void*)(do_for__+135), magic, 25);
    }

    static void do_for_(T& ctx)
    {
        void** p = (void**)((char*)&p+16);
        if (!ctx.started)
        {
            if (!ctx) return;
            ctx.started = true;
            ctx.fix = *p;
            *p = (void*)do_for_;
        }

        ctx.body(ctx);
        ctx.next();

        if (ctx)
        {
            the__();
            magic__();
            loop__();
            function__();
            here__();
        }
        else
        {
            *p = ctx.fix;
        }
    }
};

struct For0ToN : for_<For0ToN>
{
    For0ToN(int N, void(*f)(For0ToN&))
        : for_<For0ToN>(f)
        , N(N)
    {
        do_for_(*this);
    }

    operator bool() {return i < N;}
    operator int() {return i;}
    void next() {i++;}
    int count() {return i;}
    int i = 0, N = 0;
};

int main()
{
    For0ToN(10, +[](For0ToN& i)
    {
        std::cout << int(i) << ": ";
        For0ToN(i.count(), +[](For0ToN& i)
        {
            std::cout << int(i) << ". ";
        });
        std::cout << "\n";
    });
    std::cout << "done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The code is demonstrated here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dd77ade501ac748

Comment: You've mentioned the restrictions, but not what your actual task was. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: a generic way to loop without a loop

Comment: That x64 machine code in `magic` would already be tricky to read as a hexadecimal byte array, but this is just the worst possible representation

Comment: Read about `setjmp/longjmp`. Then immediately forget everything you've read.

Comment: Given that you're looking for general review and critique of a working piece of code, this question would likely be better asked on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This site is for answering specific, objective questions about programming.

Comment: You could use `std::accumulate` on a a vector or arbitrary size with a custom `BinaryOperation` and `init`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: @PeteBecker I was thinking of writing something along those lines too :-)

Comment: Who set this restriction? What is the context? There may be an "expected" way to do this if this is for a particular class or something.

Comment: Would the use of templates for a compile time loop fall under the restriction of recursion? See https://medium.com/@savas/template-metaprogramming-compile-time-loops-over-class-methods-a243dc346122

Comment: @NicholasBetsworth not a template recursion. You should be able to do loop iteration in run time as opposed to template recursion.

Comment: Also `std::for_each` :D

Comment: @MooingDuck, limited on to iterable containers.

Comment: Would it be ok to just fully unroll the loop and do the whole thing iteratively?

Comment: What is the purpose of this assignment? I doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: You say a `while` loop is not allowed, but what about `do ... while`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl asked for clarification, still not allowed.

Comment: Is this some kind of wisdom-of-the-ancients training where you discover that the loop was inside of *you* the whole time?

Comment: No loop. ***I*** am your father.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `longjmp`. Here's an example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp):

```
#include <csetjmp>
#include <iostream>

std::jmp_buf jump_buffer;

[[noreturn]] void a(int count) 
{
    std::cout << "a(" << count << ") called\n";
    std::longjmp(jump_buffer, count+1);  // setjmp() will return count+1
}

int main() { 
    // loop from 0-9

    volatile int count = 0; // local variables must be volatile for setjmp
    if (setjmp(jump_buffer) != 10) {
        a(count++);  // This will cause setjmp() to exit
    }
}
```

Comment: Ps. I've made _one_ program using `longjmp` and that was 25-30 years ago. Never again!

Comment: I think this is the much more better alternative rather than using `accumulate`, `for_each`, and others..

Comment: @PrinzRainerBuyo As far as I know (but I'm absolutely not sure) there's only one call on the stack at a time. I just started reading about it again - and I suddenly remember the headache ...

Comment: @KhalBuyo -- `longjmp` does whatever is needed to restore the context at the invocation of `setjmp`. The details depend on the compiler.

Comment: @PeteBecker True, which means that the stack _should_ be restored - so there's no risk of the stack overflowing just because of long jumping a million times. From what I've now read and the small tests I've made, that seems to hold true.

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear but 1 alternative of the loop is `std::transform()`

Answer (score 0):

Template metaprogramming is common way of avoiding writing explicit loop in code. This work gets done by compiler. Check [this](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/design/blitz/meta-art.html) for examples of factorial and bubble sort implementation without writing explicit loops. You can check this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032602/template-ing-a-for-loop-in-c) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does it count if I hide recursion into function objects and create a finite state machine?

```
struct state
{
    size_t current_column;
    size_t current_row;
    size_t max_column;
    size_t max_row;
};

typedef function<void(state&)> action_t;

struct do_item
{
    do_item(ostream& ss, action_t* move_next)
        : ss_(ss), move_next_(move_next) {}

    void operator()(state& s)
    {
        if (s.current_row == s.max_row)
        {
            ss_ << "done";
            return;
        }
        if (0 == s.current_column)
        {
            ss_ << s.current_row << ':';
        }
        if (s.max_column == s.current_column)
        {
            ss_ << '\n';
            s.current_column = 0;
            ++s.current_row;
            s.max_column = s.current_row;
        }
        else
        {
            ss_ << ' ' << s.current_column << '.';
            ++s.current_column;
        }
        (*move_next_)(s);
    }

    ostream& ss_;
    action_t* move_next_;
};

static string no_loops_challenge(size_t n)
{
    stringstream ss;
    state s = {0, 0, 0, n};
    action_t move_next;
    do_item action(ss, &move_next);
    move_next = action;
    action(s);
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: still a recursion

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using range-v3 that should satisfy all the constraints:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;
    
ranges::for_each(rv::iota(0, 10), [](int i) {
    std::cout << i << ": ";
    ranges::copy(rv::iota(0, i), 
        ranges::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ". "));
    std::cout << "\n";
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/gEtahD).